# Is there way to show disk i/o read/writes per process in real time?

Tags: activity-monitor

I am struggling to find out what process is eating away my Mac performance, and disk i/o is the culprit. Activity Monitor frequently shows megabytes of read/write, but unfortunately, it does not show the per process value (only total written by given process, which is useless).
  Is there a way to find out?
  iotop does not seem to work, because I am on Sierra, and SIP is enabled.

Thank You,
Zsolt

Answer (score 1):

[iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)  shows, among many many other things, disk activity by process. It is not free, but you can do a 14 day trial.

Comment: Wasn't this free at some point?